# Angularjs Make drop down disabled when pressing checkbox inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

- I'm trying to display on screen html controls using Meta-Data stored in json file.
- Also I'm trying to create a state where pressing check box that will make a drop down disabled.

  - I was managed to achieve this for a select box with **static** options and a select box with **dynamic** options (using ng-options).
  - I could not achieve this when wrapping it with **ng-repeat**.

I have spent a lot of time making this work but in vane.

I would appreciate if someone could pin point me to the right direction.

I have created a sample code which can be found in **Plunker** [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/f8xNEZK5h52uaITvH4nS?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) doc:

> The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a
>   collection. Each template instance gets its own scope

The trick is to add `controlChecked` to `form` and remove the `ng-init`. So they will be in the same scope.

```
<div ng-show="control.type == 'Checkbox'">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="form.controlChecked" name="{{control.id}}"/>
</div>

<div ng-show="control.type == 'DropdownList'">
     <select    ng-model="control.id" 
                ng-disabled="!form.controlChecked"
                ng-options="value.code as value.name for value in control.items" 
                name="{{control.id}}"
                >
    </select>
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/P3WyO1pXLTQBc3wGPaJ9?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Can you please explain how and why your suggestion works?
it seems that using the [form.] will do the trick, however controlChecked is not part of form

Comment: Your example works as expected. However if I have more than one check box that trigger the drop downs in the HTML.
How could I make checkbox1 influence only Dropdown1 and checkbox2 influence only Dropdown2?

Answer (score 0):

from http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat:

The `ngRepeat` directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope.

so it looks like you should use the `$parent` scope: `$parent.controlChecked`.

Comment: the other answer I got was to use [form.] and you say use [$parent.]
What is the difference between them?

Comment: yes. there are a few different ways to do it. I think `form` gets referenced in each iteration's scope, so you can use it to store your flag. I propose to store the flag in the parent scope directly.

Comment: which is better, [$parent.] for [form.]? can I use what ever verb I want such as [myList.] instead of [form.]?

Comment: if `myList` exists in the parent scope (or in a scope that is accessible in each template) then yes you can use it instead of `form`. both approaches look valid. it is a matter of preference I think.

Comment: if I have more than one check box that trigger the drop downs in the HTML. How could I make checkbox1 influence only Dropdown1 and checkbox2 influence only Dropdown2?

Comment: you can use two different flags (like `controlChecked1` and `ontrolChecked2`) maybe? If I understand correctly your problem.

Comment: Hi, you understand correctly the problem, however the ng-model value remains the same. I don't know how to make it unique per each control on the screen as you suggested, please advise.

Comment: you have two check boxes. to each one assign its own model. use the corresponding model to disable the corresponding drop downs.